# How to call a function for both int and string type in python. I have attached the snippets of my code

Tags: python, string, function, integer, function-call

```
def Print_Characters_String(n=1,name='default'):
#     n = int(input('num_of_letter:',))
    for i in name:
        print(i) 
        
Print_Characters_String(n = int(input()),name = input())
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [17], in <cell line: 6>()
      3     for i in name:
      4         print(i) 
----> 6 Print_Characters_String(n = int(input()),name = input())

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5, kamal'

Print_Characters_String(input(name))
1
Print_Characters_String(input(name))
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your function, rather, it has everything to do with `int(input())`. You really should provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is the point of the parameter `n` anyway? Why not just take the string?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because you have to separate the two inputs with a newline not a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `input()` expects its answer on a separate line. So you need to type

```
5<return>
kamal
```

If you want to be able to type `5, kamil` on a single line, call `input()` once, then split it up.

```
num, name = input().split(',')
Print_Characters_string(int(num), name.strip())
```